# customize curl function to support download and info header in php

Tags: php, curl

hi there I googled hours to build my own custom curl function:

Inputs are every thing ( URL of files,images,webpage etc...)

**I have severall scenarios:**

**scenario1**

```
$url = 'an broken link or file';
$type =  null; //not important
callCurl($url,$type,10,2);
```

I except the function return false because of  `if($curl = curl_init($url))` But not works.(I test it with a broken file url)

**scenario2**

```
$url = 'an active url file';
$type =  'info'
callCurl($url,$type,10,2);
```

I except return just size of file but it first download file then give me size of it!

**scenario3**

```
$url = 'an active url webpage';
$type =  'content'
callCurl($url,$type,10,2);
```

I except return  downloaded webpage it works. no problem!

**scenario4**

```
$url = 'an active url of file or images';
$type =  'content'
callCurl($url,$type,10,2);
```

how can I download file or images? is it same of scenario3?

**This is the function:**

```
//$type: info | content 
// info: for example size of file or webpages without downloading 
// content: dpwnloaded content (file/webpage/image/etc...) 
function callCurl($url,$type,$timeout,$ctimeout)
{
    if($curl = curl_init($url))
    {
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );//
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,$ctimeout); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout); //timeout in seconds
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);    
        $str = curl_exec($curl);
        if(curl_errno($curl))
        {
            echo curl_error($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if($type == 'info')
            {
                $info['mimeType'] = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
                $info['size'] = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
                $info['path'] = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
                $info['filename'] = substr($info['path'], strrpos($info['path'], '/') + 1);
                curl_close($curl);
                return $info;
            }
            elseif($type == 'content')
            {
                return $str;
            }

        }
    }
    echo "This URL IS NOT ACTIVE IT IS NOT 200";
    return false;
}
```

how can I change it to support those senarios?

Comment: Are you using a framework of any kind?

Comment: No...I code with notepad ++

Answer (score 0):

For scenario1: Try to change `if(curl_errno($curl))` to `if(0 != curl_errno($curl))`.

[curl_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) returns the error number or 0 (zero) if no error occurred.

For scenario2: You need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)`. This doesn't actuallly download the file but only retrieve the header. You find the `Content-Length` when you parse the returned data.